# Category objects in $\infty$-groupoids vs Complete Segal Spaces

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory, model-categories

From my understanding, one way to motivate Complete Segal Spaces is to see them as $(\infty,1)$-category objects inside the $(\infty,1)$-category of spaces, or rather $\infty$-groupoids, represented by Kan complexes.
It looks like the definition of a CSS as a bisimplicial set satisfying some conditions does precisely this.
However, if we follow the definition of a [category object in an infinity-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+object+in+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-category#PreCategoryInTopos) at the nLab, we see a somewhat subtle difference.

Let $\mathbf{Kan}$ denote the category of Kan complexes, and $\infty \mathbf{Grpd}$ denote the $(\infty,1)$-category of $\infty$-groupoids, for instance represented by the simplicial localization of $\mathbf{Kan}$.

By definition, a CSS is a **functor** $\Delta^{op} \to \mathbf{Kan}$ satisfying Segal and completeness conditions, whereas an internal $(\infty,1)$-category to $\infty \mathbf{Grpd}$ is an **$\infty$-functor** $\Delta^{op} \to \infty \mathbf{Grpd}$ satisfying similar conditions.

The relevant nLab pages at [Segal Space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Segal+space), [Complete Segal Spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complete+Segal+space) and [category object in an infinity-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+object+in+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-category#PreCategoryInTopos) seem to make no difference between the two notions. I do not doubt that the two definitions I have given here both present the theory of $(\infty,1)$-categories, but I couldn't find such an equivalence anywhere in the literature. To me it would seem like an interesting result in itself that any Complete Segal Object in the $(\infty,1)$-category $\infty \mathbf{Grpd}$ can be "strictified" to a Complete Segal Object in the category with weak equivalences $\mathbf{Kan}$.

I was wondering how to obtain such a strictification result, be it by an abstract argument or a direct construction.

As remarked by Dmitri P., if we define an $\infty$-category to be a relative category and an $\infty$-functor to be a weak equivalence-preserving functor, the question becomes tautological.
Something similar seems to happen if we take $\mathbf{Kan}$-enriched categories as models : there the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-groupoids is the $\mathbf{Kan}$-enriched category of Kan complexes, and any $\mathbf{Kan}$-enriched functor has an underlying functor. In a sense, this is because relative categories and $\mathbf{Kan}$-enriched categories are already "strict enough models" of $\infty$-categories (they have strictly defined compositions, which are strictly unital and associative, etc.).

Hence I reformulate my question as follows : is there a similar strictification result if we work with quasi-categories or Complete Segal Spaces instead ? Can it be shown to follow from the case of relative categories or $\mathbf{Kan}$-enriched categories by general model category-theoretic arguments ?

Comment: Your question is asking for a comparison between complete Segal spaces and the definition described in the nLab article using the informal language of (∞,1)-categories.  Therefore, it is not a precise mathematical question until you fix precise models for ∞-groupoids, ∞-functors, and (∞,1)-categories.

Comment: Indeed, one such model is given by taking (∞,1)-categories to mean relative categories, ∞-groupoids to mean objects in the relative category of Kan complexes, and ∞-functor to mean relative functor.  This perfectly legitimate interpretation of your question makes it tautological.  If you have other models for (∞,1)-categories in mind, perhaps they should be mentioned explicitly.